# find producers surplus

Tags: calculus

suppose the supply function of a certain item is given by S(x)= 4x +2 and demand is D(x)= 14-x^2. find producer's surplus.

I set them equal to each other and get 6, then I plug 6 into supply function and get 26.  From there I write producers formula as 26-[4x + 2]. Do the antiderivative and plug in 6. I get 0? that's not one of my answer choices? Am I missing a step?

Comment: Supply and demand will be equal at 2 and not 6.

Comment: How so? i figure x= -2? I can't use -2, right?

Comment: No, calculate again, x = 2 or -6

Comment: @nicole Try re-working the intersection. You should be solving $x^2 +4x -12=0$

Comment: You guys are right! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

At $x = 2$, $S(x) = 10$.
Draw a horizontal line at the height of 10. 
The area of the triangle formed gives the Producer Surplus.